# solr query time is long as the q term increases

Tags: solr

when I run "q=one" the Qtime is around 200ms however when I run add 2 or 3 words the run time exponentially increases eg: "q=two words" or "q=apple orange berry" resulting in 3s to 7s.

I have indexed around 10 mil document with each document containing around 100 words. I am using that usual filter factories like lowercase/synonym/stop filter. 
Found that search result retrieving part taking long time and not the faceting/highlighting/sort... see below result.

```
    "timing":{
      "time":3435.0,
      "prepare":{
        "time":0.0,
        "query":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet_module":{
          "time":0.0},
        "mlt":{
          "time":0.0},
        "highlight":{
          "time":0.0},
        "stats":{
          "time":0.0},
        "expand":{
          "time":0.0},
        "terms":{
          "time":0.0},
        "spellcheck":{
          "time":0.0},
        "debug":{
          "time":0.0}},
      "process":{
        "time":3434.0,
        "query":{
          "time":3316.0},
        "facet":{
          "time":0.0},
        "facet_module":{
          "time":0.0},
        "mlt":{
          "time":0.0},
        "highlight":{
          "time":116.0},
        "stats":{
          "time":0.0},
        "expand":{
          "time":0.0},
        "terms":{
          "time":0.0},
        "spellcheck":{
          "time":1.0},
        "debug":{
          "time":0.0}}}}}
```

Caching is working good. However I did not change any factory default settings for caching.

Used jconsole to check GC time which is around 0.23 sec.

I would like query time to fall below 1 sec.

However not sure where else to look? Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thank  you.

Comment: What is the definition of the field you're querying? What does your complete query string look like?

Comment: @MatsLindh I am querying Text_general field which is indexed and stored. Below is sample query. Let me know if you would like any other info, localhost:8983/solr/data_jan2019/blacklight?q=type:Note%20AND%20Text_decompressed:surgeon+cancelled+appointment

Comment: Be aware that those two last terms (cancelled appointment) will be made against the default search field. That might not be `Text_decompressed`.